# using keyword for make public a protected overloaded method

Tags: c++, unit-testing, using

I tried to search solution for this problem, but I could not find any.
This is my class:

```
class X;
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass();

  protected:
    // ctor for unit test
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<X> p_x);
};
```

In unit test:

```
class FakeClass : public MyClass
{
  public:
    using MyClass::MyClass;
};
```

In the tests I want to use it:

```
FakeClass myFake(std::shared_ptr<X>(new X));
```

But g++ says:

> MyClass::MyClass(std::shared_ptr)  is protected

How can be specified the exact method for using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FakeClass` can use the `MyClass` constructor, but wherever you're constructing your `FakeClass` from can't - it's not a friend or a derived type.

You'll have to write a `public` `FakeClass` constructor, and that has to be what's calling the `MyClass` protected constructor:

```
FakeClass(std::shared_ptr<X> p)
: MyClass(p)
{ }
```